# Having trouble posting a form in django and getting all the arguments

Tags: html, django

I have a form in django:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    klarf_files = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
    pixel_size = forms.CharField()
    fov = forms.CharField()
    template_recipe = forms.CharField()
    template_target = forms.CharField()
```

When I post the form I only get the klarf_files fields and not any of the others. The The form does not have the cleaned_data dictionary as the docs say it should, but I can get the files by doing this:

```
form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
files = request.FILES.getlist('klarf_files')
```

But I need the others as well. After screwing around with this for over a day I decided to just brute force it and add the parameters to the form's action attribute, e.g.:

```
$('#upload').attr('action', "?pixel_size="+$('#pixel_size').val());
```

This works, but this created a different issue: I want the form to go to a certain view. In my original form I had this:

```
<form id="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action="/report/CDSEM/DR4iBeta/dr4iupload/">
```

I added a onsubmit function so I could add my parameters to the action attribute, but that seems to make it ignore the form action. I found that it was not going the the above view, but instead to
/report/CDSEM/DR4iBeta/. So then I tried to redirect it in then onsubmit function, but that turned it into a GET and I lost the files.

I'd like to know why I'm not getting form's cleaned_data dictionary as I should, or I'd like to know how I can add the parameters and still have it be a POST and go to where I need it to.

Here is my template:

```
  <form id="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action="{% url motor.core.reports.views.upload the_controller.app.name the_controller.get_name %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="id_pixel_size">Pixel Size</label><br />
  <input type="text" value="{{ pixel_size_default }}" id="id_pixel_size" name="pixel_size">
  <label for="id_fov">FOV</label><br />
  <input value="{{ fov_default }}" id="id_fov" name="fov">
  <label for="id_template_recipe">Template Recipe</label><br />
  <input value="{{ template_recipe_default }}" id="id_template_recipe" name="template_recipe">
  <label for="id_template_target">Template Target</label><br />
  <input value="{{ template_target_default }}" id="id_template_target" name="template_target">
  <input type="file" name="klarf_files" id="klarf_files" multiple=""/>
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Upload"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: are you actually posting a `forms.Form` object in the POST?

Comment: post the view that is processing this form.

Comment: @karthikr - not sure what you mean. I'm not using the form directly in my template - I'm generating it myself. I'll update my question to show my template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form will not have cleaned_data until the form has been validated.  The traditional way to do this is to check `is_valid` in the view that accepts the form:

```
if form.is_valid():
    klarf_file = form.cleaned_data['klarf_files']
    # and further processing as needed
else:
    # traditionally you rerender the form display template here to show errors
```

I think that's the core of your problem - attempts to work around it by manually inserting parameters in the action should not be necessary at all.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So I added the is_valid() and it's returning false. It complaining saying the 4 char fields are not being provided. Yet all 4 do have values in then. It's not complaining about the file field.

Comment: Hmm.  Is your form rendering OK?  I don't see anything obviously wrong with that template.  At this point I would probably use firebug or a similar tool to check on exactly what post data the browser thinks it is submitting.

Comment: Yes, the form renders fine. I alredy did look at what the browser is sending - it just has the file field:

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="klarf_files"; filename="1242MNLI004.000-462A4N1WSEC4-2013-05-08-15-32-59.001"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Comment: It's like it's not linking up the fields in my template with the fields in the form.

Comment: If the browser is only sending the file field, that indicates something wrong in the HTML form definition itself - again, I don't see anything obvious but until the full form data is posting correctly the Django processing isn't going to work as you want it.

Comment: I figured out why it's happening, but I don't know how to fix it. These text fields have disabled="True" set on them. The user cannot type in them - their values get set programmatically from js. If I remove the disabled="True" the values flow through to the form. I need to have these fields be uneditable. Anyone know how to get them to work with django forms?

Comment: Well, there's your problem.   By definition disabled fields are not submitted - it's nothing special about django.  If you want to do the calculation client side, use hidden inputs to pass in the values - and plain text spans or something if you want to display uneditable copies prior to submission.

Comment: I ended up doing it with hidden fields that are tied to the form. The values from the "real" fields gets copied to the corresponding hidden fields by javascript. Thanks for all the help.